# Weird behaviour with ignored files and git checkout

Tags: git

Having two branches `master` and `dist`, both have the `/node_modules` entry in `.gitignore`.

Having no uncommitted/untracked files in both branches, and while I'm on master if I do `git checkout dist` then again `git checkout master`, I see that **Some** folders disappear, but **not all**

Here is the flow with commands:

```
~/p/retwisn git:master ❯❯❯ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

~/p/retwisn git:master ❯❯❯ tree node_modules -L 1
node_modules
├── connect-flash
├── connect-redis
├── express
├── grunt
├── grunt-coffeelint
├── grunt-concurrent
├── grunt-contrib-clean
├── grunt-contrib-coffee
├── grunt-contrib-copy
├── grunt-contrib-watch
├── grunt-mocha-cli
├── grunt-nodemon
├── grunt-shell
├── jade
├── mocha
├── redis
├── redis-url
├── should
├── sinon
├── swagger-node-express
└── yaml-config

~/p/retwisn git:master ❯❯❯ git checkout dist

~/p/retwisn git:dist ❯❯❯ git status
# On branch dist
nothing to commit, working directory clean

~/p/retwisn git:dist ❯❯❯ tree node_modules -L 1
node_modules
├── connect-flash
├── connect-redis
├── express
├── grunt
├── grunt-coffeelint
├── grunt-concurrent
├── grunt-contrib-clean
├── grunt-contrib-coffee
├── grunt-contrib-copy
├── grunt-contrib-watch
├── grunt-mocha-cli
├── grunt-nodemon
├── grunt-shell
├── jade
├── mocha
├── redis
├── redis-url
├── should
├── sinon
├── swagger-node-express
└── yaml-config

~/p/retwisn git:dist ❯❯❯ git checkout master

~/p/retwisn git:master ❯❯❯ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

~/p/retwisn git:master ❯❯❯ tree node_modules -L 1
node_modules
├── grunt-contrib-clean
├── grunt-nodemon
└── swagger-node-express
```

Although /node_modules is ignored, somehow when switching back to master, some subfolders got deleted.

Comment: Does your repo contain `node_modules`? (You say it's ignored, but you don't say whether it was added to your repo anyway.)

Comment: @hvd how can I check? Does `git ls-tree HEAD` do the job? According to this command, `node_modules` is not in the tree.

Comment: @hvd But I do see `node_modules` on `dist` branch.

Comment: That’s why it’s removed then. When you are on the dist branch, those folders belong to the branch. When you switch to master, master doesn’t contain them, so they are removed when switching over.

Comment: @poke @hvd I see, thanks. I removed the folder from `dist` branch, committed, and now checkouts work without touching the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: @hvd Would you write a quick short answer so SelimOber can accept it and mark the question as answered?

Comment: @Quentin By the time the question was solved, the answer didn’t exist yet (see comments above). I’m sure Selim will do that when he gets the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Expanding briefly from the comments)

Git uses `.gitignore` to know which unversioned files should be left alone. However, if files are already versioned, they're part of the repo, and git will not simply skip those files. In your case, your dist branch contains files that are not part of the master branch, so when you switch from dist to master, those files get removed. The solution you found, removing those files from the dist branch, is the right one: presumably, the files are in `.gitignore` because they should not be part of the repo, and you fixed the repo so that those files indeed are not a part of it.